# Get time Elapsed in Yammer

Tags: java, timer, yammer

I am trying to get the time elapsed for function calls and getting them on the JMX port. I found out yammer would be suitable for this. Though the counter was straight forward, its confusing using the timer.

```
 private Timer executeTimer;
 TimerContext timerContext;
 obj.timerContext = obj.executeTimer.time();
 .
 .
 .
 public void f()
   {
      //start timer
      f2();
      //stop timer
      //display time difference
   }
```

I know it would look too trivial for some of you, please bear with me. I am new to yammer and finding it confusing which function and which class to use. Also if you can tell me when TimerContext is used and when Timer is used, it would be very helpful.

Comment: See this. https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/blob/master/metrics-core/src/main/java/com/codahale/metrics/Timer.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to initialise the ExecuteTimer Instance.

```
executeTimer=Metrics.newTimer(CLASSNAME.class, "Metrics_Name", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

After that, do it like this:-

```
 private Timer executeTimer;
 TimerContext timerContext;
 obj.timerContext = obj.executeTimer.time();
 .
 .
 .
 public void f()
   {
       timerContext = executeTimer.time();//start timer
       f2();
       timerContext.stop();//stop timer
       //All stats are sent to JMX port by default. You can open console to view them
   }
```

TO get more into the stuff, here the actual code is.

https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/blob/master/metrics-core/src/main/java/com/codahale/metrics/Timer.java

Comment: Thanks , but I want to display it as well, can I do it?